# element should be highlighted by default

Tags: css

Всем привет! Я учусь верстать сайт по макету из Фигмы и столкнулась с требованием при стилизации 1го элемента списка: element should be highlighted by default при создании интерактивной панели навигации. Как это осуществить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавить этому элементу класс `active` например? И чтобы на этом классе висели стили для активного элемента.

Answer (score 0):

Видать дизайнер указал, что он в макете не отображал ховер эффекты не потому что он их профтыкал, а потому что он желает что б они были "по умолчанию". И зависили от браузера пользователя. Светло синими были для Хрома.